# How to change a property depending on a condition on CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I am working on a project where depending on the development environment it will show a different page in a UserPoolClient callbackURL, but I had this error:

```
Property validation failure: [Value of property {/CallbackURLs} does not match type {Array}]
```

The code I used is like the following, I'm not sure if this is the correct way to add an **if** condition. I tried to follow the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) but I don't have experience on AWS.

```
Conditions:
  IsProd: !Equals [ !Ref EnvType, 'prod']

  UserPoolApiClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Properties:
      ClientName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-user-pool-client'
      UserPoolId: !Ref UserPool
      GenerateSecret: false
      SupportedIdentityProviders:
        - COGNITO
      ExplicitAuthFlows:
        - USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
      CallbackURLs:
        !If
          - IsProd
          - Fn::Sub: '{!ImportValue landing-page}'
          - Fn::Sub: '{!ImportValue landing-page}/dev_welcome.html'
```

Comment: It wants CallbackURLs to be an array. You passed it just a single value. Put a dash before it to force an array.

Comment: Thank you kichik, I didn't know that forcing an array was with - instead of [].

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0):

`CallbackURLs` should be a list:

```
      CallbackURLs:
        - !If
           - IsProd
           - Fn::Sub: '{!ImportValue landing-page}'
           - Fn::Sub: '{!ImportValue landing-page}/dev_welcome.html'
```